# WPF Textbox max length for fractional value

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have a textbox in wpf and want to restrict it to enter max 6 digits before decimal and only two digits after decimal.
eg 123456.25. 
I know MaxLength is there but how to handle the fractional part? Any suggestion pls?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using DataBinding for the TextBox content, it can be simply achieved by specifying StringFormat to your binding, for instance:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourProperty, StringFormat=\{0:F2\}}"/>
```

See number formatting documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're not using DataBinding, I'm sure someone else will provide an answer for you.